# how to interact with UITextField (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I’m new in iOS dev with swift 3
I would like to display the result  of calculations with UITextField so to display + - / * bottoms  i have implemented a toolBar with items above number pad but i can’t interact with UITextField without an error .
I passed some hours to read and i found some solutions with action parameter but none worked.

func addDoneButtonOnNumpad(textField: UITextField) {

```
    let keypadToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar()

    // add a done button to the numberpad
    keypadToolbar.items=[
        UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: textField, action: #selector(UITextField.resignFirstResponder)),
        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil),

        UIBarButtonItem(title: "+", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(self.addSum(_:))),
        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil),
        UIBarButtonItem(title: "-", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: textField, action: #selector(UITextField.resignFirstResponder)),
        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil),
        UIBarButtonItem(title: "/", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: textField, action: #selector(UITextField.resignFirstResponder)),
        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil),
        UIBarButtonItem(title: "=", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: textField, action: #selector(UITextField.resignFirstResponder))
    ]
    keypadToolbar.sizeToFit()
    // add a toolbar with a done button above the number pad
    textField.inputAccessoryView = keypadToolbar
}



@IBAction func addSum(_ sender: UITextField)
{

    sender.insertText("+")

}
```

I change my code thanks to NDoc now i find an error of uncaught exception of type NSException i dont know what is mean but i suppose like a segmentation fault maybe.

Furthermore  i linked my IBAction with the UIextfield that i would like to interact.
In fact i would like to  add + or - or / or *  to the number in the UITextFieldand do the math with an another and   display 
the result in the same UITextField.

Regards

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIscv.png

Comment: Please edit your question to include a TEXT version of your code and indicate the line you are having an error on. Link only questions are bad because they become useless once the links expire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all change your `selector` syntax like this.

```
UIBarButtonItem(title: "+", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(self.sayHello(_:)))
```

Now in `swift 3.0` you need to pass the name of first parameter, so change your `sayHello` action like this.

```
func sayHello(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
     theTextField.text = "Hello!"
}
```

**Note:** The parameter type of method is either `AnyObject` or `UIBarButtonItem`, not the `NSButton` as on the above answer.

Comment: Thanks for your code snippet. i tried it and its working.

Comment: Your response helped me to understand the syntax of selector and interaction with the button  but i am still stuck.

Comment: Then you need to add new post on SO with your new problem.

Comment: There is no reputation limit for posting a question, you can post question with 1 reputation also.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Objective-C method you want to connect to a button then you'd use the string format for action that you're using. (Although come to think of it I think Swift 3 is dropping the string style of defining a selector, so you should get in the habit of always using `#selector`.)

For a Swift IBAction method you'd be better off using #selector, which takes a Swift function definition, like

```
#selector(sayHello(_:))
```

Note that unless you've created a custom subclass of UITextField, you can't send a message like sayHello to a `UITextField`.

You typically make your view controller the target for your actions, and then implement a method in your view controller that handles the action and does things like installing messages into the text field.

your code might look like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done",
  style: .done,
  target: self
  action:  #selector(sayHello(_:))
```

And you might define a sayHello method in your view controller like this:

```
@IBAction func sayHello(sender: NSButton) {
  theTextField.text = "Hello!"
}
```

P.S. Don't post screen-shots of code. Paste the code into your question, select it, and use the code tool to format it as source code. If you want to show the error you can include a screen-shot ALSO, but always put your code into your question as formatted text.

Comment: Thanks for your fast  response, I tried to change in my code but it isn't working anyway with the selector syntax i am new so i must forgot something. I didn't create subclass of UITextField my final purpose is to do calculation in UI Text field like 5 + 7 for example but i can't create a button in storyboard because my toolbar is an extension of the number pad.

Comment: If you're new then you need to slow down. Edit your question to show your new code at the bottom, along with the error you are getting.

Comment: Several of the things you just said don't make sense to me. You won't "do calculation[s] in UITextField". You'll display the results of a calculation in a text field. I also don't understand what you meant by "...my toolbar is an extension of the number pad."

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation i edited my post and i hope it is more understanding.  Thank you for your time !